# Проблема с регистром postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Можно в базе как-то отключить чувствительность к регистру?
Для обращения к таблице `Users` так

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

без кавычек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так нельзя. Если название таблиц или колонок не маленькими буквами, тогда всегда нужно брать на двойные кавычки.

Рекомендуется всегда использовать малые буквы, что бы работало и без кавычек и с кавычками одинаково.

[Документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)