# Как удалить супер пользователя в postgresql?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Создал супер пользователя, этой командой `createuser --interactive`

```
Denisoed | Суперпользователь, Создаёт роли, Создаёт БД
```

а удалить не получается.

Пишу `DROP ROLE Denisoed;` в ответ приходит:

> ОШИБКА:  роль "denisoed" не существует!

Comment: Что выдает `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;`? Там есть такая роль? Регистр букв совпадает?

Comment: А если `DROP ROLE 'Denisoed';` (внимание на одинарные кавычки)?

Comment: @AlexKrass Выдает **pg_signal_backend
 Denisoed
 postgres
(3 строки)**

Comment: @D-side **ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "'Denisoed'")
СТРОКА 1: DROP ROLE 'Denisoed';**

Comment: ...или там нужны двойные?

Comment: @D-side СПАСИБО =)! Я тоже толь с одинарными пробовал, ничего не получалось. Плюс еще не внимательность( ведь в ошибке вокруг имени пользователя по три кавычки

Comment: Не знаю, дубликат ли, но проблема та же самая: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579853/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-postgresql

Comment: @D-side так при создании пользователя таким образом **ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD pass**, одинарные кавычки не считаются синтаксической ошибкой. И пользователь успешно удаляется

Comment: В Postgresql одинарные и двойные кавычки [носят разное значение](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/sql-syntax-lexical.html). Двойные для идентификаторов, одинарные для строковых констант. Достаточно не привычно их чередовать, к примеру, в подобной конструкции `CREATE DATABASE "TestDatabase" WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8'`. И ведь нельзя заменить одни на другие.

Comment: @AlexKrass Спасибо за помощь =)